# Show that $\frac{3}{2} \leq h_n \leq 2$ for all $n \geq 2$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let a sequence be given by $D_{n+1}=D_n+D_{n−1}$ where $D_1=1$ and $D_2=2$.

Let $h_n=\frac{D_n}{D_{n-1}}$ for all $n \geq  2$.

How would you show that $\frac{3}{2} \leq h_n \leq 2$ for all $n \geq  2$?

This is what I'm thinking...

Let $n=2$.

Then $h_2= \frac {D_2}{D_{2-1}}= \frac{2}{1}= 2$.

Thus, $\frac{3}{2} \leq h_n \leq 2$.

Now let $n=k+1$ such that $k \in N$.

Then $h_{k+1}= \frac {D_{k+1}}{D_{k}}= 1 + \frac{D_{k-1}}{D_{k}}= 1 + \frac{1}{h_k} \leq 2$.

After this step, this is where I get stuck. I know I have show that any $h_n \leq$2, but how do I show that $3/2 \leq h_n$? Could someone please explain/show.

Comment: Since by assumption, $\frac{3}{2} \leq h_{k} \leq 2$, then $\frac{2}{3} \geq \frac{1}{h_{k}} \geq \frac{1}{2}$ which implies that $\frac{5}{3} \geq 1+\frac{1}{h_{k}} \geq \frac{3}{2}$. And then you're done.

Comment: Why $\frac{5}{3}$ $\geq$ $1+\frac{1}{h_k}$ $\geq$ $\frac{3}{2}$? Specifically where did the $\frac{5}{3}$ come from and how does this show that it works for all $h_n$.

Comment: I just added 1 to each of them.

Answer (score 1):

$$h_{k+1}=\frac{D_{k+1}}{D_k} = 1+\frac{D_{k-1}}{D_k} = 1 + \frac{1}{h_k}$$